# Removing Second Entry from filtered ROWS PL SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Given 3 tables city, country, Continent, return the number of cities that are part of a country that is in 2 or more continents.
The output should be in the following format:
Country, Code, Continent1, Continent2, Count of Cities

**City**

| name | country |
| --- | --- |
| Moscow | R |
| Test | R |

**Country**

| name | code |
| --- | --- |
| Russia | R |

**Continent**

| country | continent |
| --- | --- |
| R | Europe |
| R | Asia |

I have this working until here :

```
    SELECT contCtry.nm   AS Country,
       contCtry.ctry AS Code,
       contCtry.co1  "Con1",
       contCtry.co2  "Con 2",
       contCtry.ctr  AS "Count of Cities"
FROM   (SELECT c1.NAME        nm,
               c.country      ctry,
               e.continent    co1,
               cont.continent co2,
               Count(c.NAME)  ctr
        FROM   city c
               JOIN continent e
                 ON c.country = e.country
                    AND e.country IN (SELECT ct.code
                                      FROM   country ct
                                             JOIN continent ec
                                               ON ct.code = ec.country
                                      GROUP  BY ct.code
                                      HAVING Count(ct.code) > 1)
               JOIN country c1
                 ON c1.code = e.country
               JOIN continent cont
                 ON cont.country = e.country
        WHERE  cont.continent != e.continent
        GROUP  BY c1.NAME,
                  c.country,
                  e.continent,
                  cont.continent) contCtry
ORDER  BY contCtry.co1,
          contCtry.co2,
          contCtry.nm;
```

The output looks like this :

| Country | Code | Cont1 | Cont2 | CT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Russia | R | Asia | Europe | 2 |
| Russia | R | Europe | Asia | 2 |

How do I get ride of this second row. I have tried many things, but its not working. Thank you for your help and advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT MAX(country.name) AS Country,
       country.Code,
       MIN(continent.continent) AS Continent1,
       MAX(continent.continent) AS Continent2,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM city WHERE city.country = country.code)
         AS Count_of_Cities
FROM   country
       INNER JOIN continent
       ON country.code = continent.country
GROUP BY
       country.code
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT continent.continent) > 1
```

or:

```sql
SELECT country.name AS Country,
       country.Code,
       continent.continent1,
       continent.continent2,
       city.Count_of_Cities
FROM   ( SELECT country,
                MIN(continent) AS continent1,
                MAX(continent) AS continent2
         FROM   continent
         GROUP BY country
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       ) continent
       INNER JOIN country
       ON country.code = continent.country
       INNER JOIN (
          SELECT country,
                 COUNT(*) AS count_of_cities
          FROM   city
          GROUP BY country
       ) city
       ON city.country = country.code
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE City (name, country) AS
SELECT 'City1', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'City2', 'C' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Country (name, code) AS
SELECT 'Country1', 'C' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Continent (country, continent) AS
SELECT 'C', 'Continent1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'Continent2' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| COUNTRY | CODE | CONTINENT1 | CONTINENT2 | COUNT_OF_CITIES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Country1 | C | Continent1 | Continent2 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xRZIdFKw)